# Delete image after uloading image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-4

i want to delete an image after uploading. the images are showing after uploading. But now the user also has to get the oppertunity to delete a image But if I select an image and press delete nothing happens I have this for view:

```
<div id="tabs-3">


           @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadMorePhotos", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
           {
               @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


            <div class="form-field">
                <p>Select pictures:</p>
                <div class="upload-container">
                    <div class="upload">
                        <input type="file" name="files" value="" multiple="multiple" id="file1" />

                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/deleteButton.png")" alt="Remove picture." />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-field">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </div>

    <br />

      foreach (var item in Model.LolaBikePhotos )
       {
        <img src="~/Images/profile/@item.ImagePath" alt="" height=150 width=200 />

           using (Html.BeginForm("Account", "DeleteFiles", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
           {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>File Name</td>
                </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="files" value="@item.ImagePath" />
                        </td>
                        <td>@item.ImagePath</td>
                    </tr>
                            </table>

            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
           }




       }





           }

       <br />


        </div>
```

and this is my action method:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            foreach (var id in files)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(id.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/profile" + @"\" + fileName.Replace('+', '_')));
                var file = db.lolabikerPhotos.Find(id);

                // you now have access to the information of the file, including path, name, etc

                // delete file using your filepath (path + filename)
               System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            }


            return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-3");

        }
```

Comment: The image is not removed from the backend either? Your application has proper delete rights for that folder?

Comment: yes, it has proper right to delete but the strange thing is that If I put breakpoint on de delete action method it will not be hit

Comment: And is my body header correct?   public ActionResult DeleteFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)

Comment: What I do wrong? Somebody?

Comment: ?? will be nice to get some advise

Comment: Does it even reach the foreach then?

Comment: yes, it reach the foreach